# A combinatorial proof of an identity involving Euler’s $ \phi $-function.

Tags: combinatorics, totient-function, combinatorial-proofs

My assignment is to prove this:

> **Problem.** For an integer $ n \geq 1 $, show that $ \displaystyle n = \sum_{d|n} \phi \! \left( \frac{n}{d} \right) $.

I have a hint: Define an equivalence relation $ \sim $ on $ \mathbb{N} $ by $ a \sim b \iff \gcd(n,a) = \gcd(n,b) $.

Comment: So have you tried using the hint?

Comment: Oh I didn't mention my try. I tried to define an equivalence relation A whose  equivalence classes are parametrized by divisors of n. But I cannot understand that |A_d| = Phi(n/d).

Comment: Well, suppose $\gcd(a,n) = d$. What do you think you get from $\gcd(a/d,n/d)$? And how many $a/d$ satisfy that?

Comment: Do you mean that the hint is (n,a)=(n,b)=d ?

Comment: Well $\gcd(a,n) =$ something, and I might as well call it $d$, since I know it divides $n$.

Comment: I am really sorry for not knowing the meaning of $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start out with the hint. I assume you can verify that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

We can define the set $H_d = \{a \in \mathbb N\ |\ a \leq n, \gcd(a,n) = d\}$. Because $\sim$ is an equivalence class, all of the $H_d$ are disjoint for each $d|n$ and the size of their union is $n$:
$$n = \sum_{d|n}|H_d|$$

So we want to see how big each $H_d$ is. Suppose that $m \in H_d$
$$\Leftrightarrow \gcd(m,n) = d$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \gcd(m/d, n/d) = 1$$

Why? Because if there was anything left over after dividing by the $\gcd$, it would have been possible to select a larger initial $\gcd$, a contradiction. So now we have a better definition for $H_d$ (rename $a = kd$, since we know $d|a$):
$$H_d = \{k \in \mathbb N \ |\ k \leq n, \gcd(k, n/d) = 1\}$$

But we know what this is - $H_d$ is the set of all integers coprime to $n/d$ and smaller than $n/d$, and there are exactly $\phi(n/d)$ of these. Put that in the original sum, and we get
$$n = \sum_{d|n}|H_d| = \sum_{d|n}\phi(n/d)$$

Comment: I am really thank you for the kind answer :)